# How to manage a plethora of development and release installers

Tags: git, jenkins, tags, versioning, release-management

Gist of problem – developing we have many installers generated through pipelines we have set up in Jenkins. The pipelines use git to get version information – which is the last tag, plus commit count. The version tag is set based off the year, quarter, and release # of that quarter – so for instance, it could look like 2020.4.1 for year 2020, quarter 4, release 1 of quarter 4.  Jenkins jobs are run per pushed commit to the repository - so there are many installers.

For user facing strings we want to keep the version to only be three components - `<year>.<quarter>.<release>`.
However, for development, it’s useful to have more information on specifically what installer we are using – so a commit count appended, works for that case. However, we don't want this additional number in the release version.

My question is, how do I combine these two situations of development versus release installers smoothly? We would like to allow the tester to easily distinguish different installers, but do want the user facing strings to not contain that additional information. We are pulling the version info from the executable, however we can re-create the version string elsewhere if needed.

Are there any good industry standards, or better ways to handle for this situation? We are not opposed to improving our build flow – we just don’t have a DevOps expert that could answer these questions for us.

Thanks for any constructive feedback and/or resources – it’s always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can introduced a different option to your executable:

- `-v` (`--version`) remains the user front-facing version that you have defined
- `-b` (`--build`) can display internl build information, like the one returned by a [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe), to get a precise Git SHA + last Git tag.